# ANSI C: Error checking user input with a function

Tags: c, function, error-handling, ansi-c

I am attempting to use a single error checking function to check for errors within multiple other functions. However, When running the program, it gets stuck in a loop and won't break from it. Once the application gets a valid input, it should continue to the next function. However it repeats the fStartBalance function even if the error checking returns a 0. I'm kind of a beginner, so I'm not too good at troubleshooting. Here is the applicable code:

```
/* Begin fValidateFloat */
int fValidateFloat(float input, float minValue, float maxValue)
{
    int failed = 0;

    while (input < minValue)
    {
        printf("\nError: Input too low, please enter a value greater than or equal to %.2f.", minValue);
        failed = 1;
        return failed;
    }
    while (input > maxValue)
    {
        printf("\nError: Input too high, please enter a value less than or equal to %.2f.", maxValue);
        failed = 1;
        return failed;
    }
} /* End fValidateFloat */

/* Begin fStartBalance */
float fStartBalance(void)
{
    float startBalance; /* Declare variable */
    int failed;

    while (failed = 1)
    {
        printf("\n\nNow enter your current balance in dollars and cents: "); /* Prompt user to input current balance */
        scanf("%f", &startBalance);
        fflush(stdin);
        failed = fValidateFloat(startBalance, 0, 3.4e+38);
    }

    return startBalance; /* Return variable */
} /* End fStartBalance */
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at the `while` loop: you want to check if `failed` is equal to 1. Instead, though, you are setting it to 1! Use `failed == 1` instead.

Comment: Remember to turn all your warnings on.  At the very least use `-Wall` if you are using `gcc`.  It will warn you about silly mistakes like your `failed = 1` typo.

Comment: the 'while' statements in function: fValidateFloat never execute in a loop, so would be better written as 'if' statements

Comment: regarding that (previously commented) while loop by @Riley, the variable 'failed' is not initialized to any specific value (just what ever happens to be on the stack at that address.  Suggest: set the 'failed' variable to some known value when declaring it.  this is also a prime example of why the literal should be on the left side, so the compiler would catch these kinds of errors, so you don't have to.

Comment: the call to scanf needs attention for: 1) the format string needs a leading ' ' to consume white space, like the prior newline 2) the returned value needs to be checked to assure the operation/format conversion(s) was successful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fflush(stdin);` is undefined

You never return any value from `fValidateFloat()` in the case the while statements are not taken:

```
        return failed;
    }
} /* End fValidateFloat */
```

In the same function while loops don't make any sense, use an if statement instead:

```
while (input < minValue)
{
    printf("\nError: Input too low, please enter a value grea%.2f.", minValue);
    failed = 1;
    return failed;
}
```

You are setting failed to 1 in the while loop, instead of comparing it to 1:

```
while (failed = 1)
```